# Azure Blob Storage - Find Blobs By Tags - Find blobs where tag is not set

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

Azure Blob storage supports getting lists of blobs based on tags on those blobs being set to certain values
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags, here, a query must be constructed using [this syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/find-blobs-by-tags?tabs=azure-ad#constructing-a-search-expression).

I can't see how I can construct a query for e.g. "Get blobs where the tag 'mytag' is not set at all".

Can anyone help me?

I have tried queries such as `where "mytag" != 'somearbitraryvalue'`, but this did not return any blobs which had no "mytag" tag.

Comment: 'The where URI parameter finds blobs in the storage account whose tags match an expression. The expression must evaluate to true for a blob to be returned in the result set.'  and also != is not under the supported ANSI SQL operators described in the link you have pasted. I am afraid this looks like not possible, you need to find another way

Answer (score 0):

Purhaps not very efficient, but what you can do is get a list of all blobs. Then iterate across them looking for ones where no tags are set.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/6009